# JavaScript Short-Circuit Variable Assignment with Commas

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, short-circuiting

I am reviewing some code for a JavaScript widget that I downloaded and there is a variable assignment similar to the following:

```
var a = a.something || a.somethingElse, c, d, e, f, g;
```

What I am wondering is if this is equivalent to this:

```
var a = a.something || a.somethingElse;
var c, d, e, f, g;
```

or this:

```
var a = a.something || a.somethingElse || c || d || e || f || g;
```

I have been reading up on short-circuit evaluation and assignments, and I understand that the first part is saying:

```
if ( a.something != (null or 0 or false)) {
    a = a.something;
} else {
    a = a.somethingElse;
}
```

but I cannot seem to find any resources that use an example like this one.

Thanks, for your help!

Comment: See [MDN: var#Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Syntax)

Comment: You forgot `""`, `undefined` and `NaN` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. A comma seperated list in a var statement is treated like individual Ines.

As for the boolean OR statement: If the first expression is falsy, the second will be used. You can add more, as in your third example.

Comment: Thanks so much - exactly the confirmation that I was looking for